# why does backwards selection in regsubsets (R, leaps package) yield nonsensical results after rearranging variables in data frame?

Tags: r, linear-regression, feature-selection

I am attempting to do forwards and backwards selection using the Boston data from the MASS package with the regsubsets() function in the leaps package in R and to compare the models selected of each size. I observe that I get different results in backwards selection in terms of which variables are in included of models of each size after I rearrange the columns of my data and re-run the algorithm.

To start, this works fine:

```
library(leaps)
library(MASS)
# Boston data: split into training and test
set.seed(12345)
test_inds <- sample(1:nrow(Boston), size=nrow(Boston)/2, replace=FALSE)
bos_train <- Boston[-test_inds,]

# outcome is per capita crime rate = crim

# forward stepwise regression
bos_fwd <- regsubsets(crim ~., data=bos_train,
                      method="forward", nvmax=ncol(bos_train))

# backward stepwise regression
bos_back <- regsubsets(crim ~., data=bos_train,
                       method="backward", nvmax=ncol(bos_train))

# plot using the method from regsubsets
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(bos_fwd, main="Forward selection", scale="r2")
plot(bos_back, main="Backward selection", scale="r2")
```

That gives me these plots, so far so good: [stepwise regression plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK1v3.png)

However, I don't think the order of the variables used in the plot is immediately interpretable and it's hard to compare the models from each selection method this way. It looks like the plot.regsubsets function is just using the order as the variables were in the original data frame, so I do some rearranging by re-ordering the columns by the selecion order for the forwards selection version of the algorithm and then re-run the regsubsets function using both forwards and backwards stepwise selection. In theory, this should give me the exact same sequences of models as before.

```
# for plotting to go nicer, re-order variables in forward-selected order
# and re-fit the models
bos_order_fwd <- names(bos_train)[bos_fwd$vorder][-1]
bos_train2 <- bos_train[,c("crim",bos_order_fwd)]
bos_fwd2 <- regsubsets(crim ~., data=bos_train2,
                      method="forward", nvmax=ncol(bos_train2))
bos_back2 <- regsubsets(crim ~., data=bos_train2,
                       method="backward", nvmax=ncol(bos_train2))

# plot using the method from regsubsets
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(bos_fwd2, main="Forward selection", scale="r2")
plot(bos_back2, main="Backward selection", scale="r2")
# observe selection orders in backward selection inconsistent with algo
```

I want to compare what the models look like for each number of variables included, so that gives me these plots: [variable selection with reordering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVzLY.png). While the forwards selection plot looks as intended, the backwards selection plot now suggests that variables were not actually selected in an order consistent with the backwards selection algorithm!

With backwards selection, it should always be the case that once a variable is excluded (white box), it is excluded from all smaller models (white boxes filling down the rest of the column). I see that this is true before I re-ordered the columns, but is no longer the case after re-ordering and re-fitting: for example, a model containing 5 non-intercept variables has {rad, medv, black, dis, zn}, one with 4 variables has {rad, medv, dis, zn}, and one with 3 variables has {rad, medv, black}. This violation of model nesting does not make any sense to me.

I can also verify the problem is in the object returned by regsubsets and not just the summary or plotting methods by comparing models in my bos_back object (no re-arranging) with models in my bos_back2 object (after rearranging).

```
> # compare the backwards stepwise models of each size
> coef(bos_back, 2)
(Intercept)         rad        medv 
  2.5800690   0.6055753  -0.1947727 
> coef(bos_back2, 2)
(Intercept)         rad        medv 
  2.5800690   0.6055753  -0.1947727 
> coef(bos_back, 3)
(Intercept)         dis         rad        medv 
  4.5777240  -0.4322162   0.5569806  -0.1925573 
> coef(bos_back2, 3)
(Intercept)         rad        medv       black 
 8.12946740  0.54926726 -0.17165228 -0.01534486 
> coef(bos_back, 4)
(Intercept)          zn         dis         rad        medv 
 7.01168924  0.07265221 -1.02796588  0.53498337 -0.22889528 
> coef(bos_back2, 4)
(Intercept)         rad        medv         dis          zn 
 7.01168924  0.53498337 -0.22889528 -1.02796588  0.07265221 
> coef(bos_back, 5)
(Intercept)          zn         dis         rad       black        medv 
11.50765180  0.06724239 -0.93907507  0.49208150 -0.01350222 -0.20607369 
> coef(bos_back2, 5)
(Intercept)         rad        medv       black         dis          zn 
11.50765180  0.49208150 -0.20607369 -0.01350222 -0.93907507  0.06724239
```

These sequences of models should be the same, but they differ when 3 variables are included. What's going on? Thanks in advance for any insight.